# Android, Allow user to select audio profile and save that choice for later use

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

The tutorials I see is allowing user to activate audio/sound profile by clicking the button immediately, i dont want to active selected profile immediately, i want to save user's choice for sound profile and activate that choice later with respect to some event, how can i do that, also suggest some good source to learn audio related things in android. I also want to do same treatment for ringer, message and notification volumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android preferences to save the user's choices for later use:

```
//save prefs
public void savePrefs(String key, Boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

//get prefs
private String loadPreferences(String key, Boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String data = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, value);
    return data;
}
```

If the user clicks audio button, set audioChoice = true in your code.  Then save audioChoice into preferences:

```
private boolean audioChoice = false;

audioChoice = savePrefs("Choice", audioChoice);
```

If you want to retrieve audioChoice at a later time, do this:

```
audioChoice = loadPreferences("Choice", audioChoice);
```

If you want more information, here is the android documentation on using SharedPreferences:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Hello Sarah, I updated my answer to include a link to the Android documentation on this topic.  SharedPreferences is going to take a little getting used to.  You should try out the my code example though.

Comment: what about user interface, would it be button with image of silent, loud or something, and when user touches that button i will save preferences for button id, on the other side on i will get prefrences and on the basis of id i will activate that audio profile, is it right?

Comment: oh sorry @josh, the fault was mine i didnt see whole code, you defined saveprefs above, also tell me are these only 3 types(string,int,boolean) of data we can save in shared prefrence, what about if i want to save double datatype in shared prefrence

Comment: Yes, when user touches the button you will save preferences.  When you are ready to activate the audio profile, you will retrieve preferences.   By the way, I used boolean variable in the example, but of course you can use int, String, etc.

Comment: You can also do float or long, but not double. This documentation shows what datatypes SharedPreferences supports: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: And is it any method toDouble or toFloat like toString()

Comment: You can cast a double to a float... double d = 3.0; float f = (float) d;

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it answers your question, thx :) –

Comment: Be patience @josh, answer my new question ;)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906439/android-gray-out-seek-bars-unless-radio-button-is-selected