# Android, Gray out seek bars unless radio button is selected

Tags: android, view, slider, radio-button, android-widget

I'm restricting user to either select default audio profiles or customized audio setting, for this purpose I'm using radio button for profiles and customized audio settings, so if user select customized settings all seek bars are reactive for use, Is there any way to do this, also numbers at seek bars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a SeekBar ?
If that's so, you may want to set the enabled attribute to false by default :

```
android:enabled="false"
```

so that, when your RadioButton is checked, you set the attribute to true programmatically

```
yourButton.setEnabled(true);
```